# Will increasing my RAM reduce the size of my w3wp.exe in memory

Tags: iis-7, w3wp

I have a asp.net web site. I have an image being updated via a timer as many times as possible every second with an image the size of 720x576.  I control when the image can be updated by initiating the next ashx page call to get my image after the img control has finished loading the previous image (I do this on the 'onload' event).

My w3wp.exe currently stands at 140,000k and it drops to 130,000. Frequently going up and down between these 2 values.

As i am testing with 1 User and as I am on a cheap VPS shared hosting environment my question is when I go Live will the w3wp.exe become uncontrollable or will the fact that by upgrading my server package (mainly increasing RAM) help to keep this all under control n a multi-user environment?

This is my Javascript:

```
        var timer3;
        var intervalLive = 50;

        function play2() {
            if (timer3) window.clearTimeout(timer3);
            swapImages3();
        }

        function setImageSrc3(src) {
            _imgLive.src = src;
            timer3 = window.setTimeout(swapImages3, intervalLive);
        }

        function swapImages3() {
            var imgCached = new Image();
            imgCached.onload = function () {
                setImageSrc3(imgCached.src);
            };
            imgCached.onerror = function () {
                setImageSrc3("http://a URL/images/ERROR.jpg");
            };
            imgCached.onload = function () {
                setImageSrc3(imgCached.src);
            };
            imgCached.src = null;
            imgCached.src = 'http://A URL/Cloud/LiveXP.ashx?id=' + new Date().getTime() + '&Alias=' + alias;
        }
```

And this is in my ashx page:

```
public class Live : IHttpHandler {
    DAL dal = new DAL();
    static byte[] StandardError = Shared.ERROR;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString["Alias"] != null)
            {
                data = Shared.GetFrame(context.Request.QueryString["Alias"].ToString());
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            data = StandardError;
            dal.AddError(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

thanks

Comment: I don't see the relation between both. Why exactly you think that increasing your RAM will cause the processes to use less of it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback.  Well this was my question. I had only considered this may be the case because I am guessing that when my image loads the w3wp process goes up and when the image is disposed and collected via garbage collection the memory goes back down.  I was wondering whether the process of garbage collection be speeded up if I had more RAM?  At the moment my VPS is 2GB RAM on my shared VPS hosting package. Like Is I said this is all new to me.

Comment: On the contrary, it will have less reasons to frequently dispose memory considering it has more RAM available.

Comment: Thinking about that you just said you are correct (need another coffee :). OK, will increasing the RAM have any benefit In any way for what I am trying to do?  Would it make the images load quicker?

Comment: I don't think so, but your plan of constantly refreshing an image pretty much without a pause seems a little excessive. You will be consuming a lot of bandwidth from your users, what can be very unconfortable to them considering not everyone has a decent Internet connection, and from your server what can be expensive for you sinse you probably have a monthly upload limit. You are doing everything that should be avoided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts. The client app is targeted. The issue of constantly showing a live stream is what the requirement is. I cannot just say you cant have it.  My task is find the most efficient way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: but are quite correct about costs - unless we use a dedicated server.

Comment: Use a video. A good codec optimizes the frames reutilizing information the client already have to generate less traffic. There are server tools specific for this task, you can even make a live stream, and include sound. Thats what everyone does, theres no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I know about this. The trouble is I am supplied with a constant stream of images from a client in jpeg format.  i had looked at streaming these images into ogg files using ffmpeg (which I achieved on the client) but I need real-time access and the ogg file has to be 'closed' before it can be played. I have a spent a long time at trying to achieve what you suggested but in this scenario I am struggling :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can mixup ffmpeg, ffplay and something feeding those beasts with a river of jpegs and come up with a live stream. There is even a Apache module specific to work with that, I don't even know what it does exactly, all I know is that it is possible. Unfortunately I have no experience in this matter, but Googling a little I'm sure you will find out how.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your comments. I know nothing about apache. I doknow asp.net. I had spent some time Googling about ffserver but still cannot find any practical examples using it in managed code.  The quest continues :)

Comment: just in case anyone else was following this ffserver is not available for Windows..